# Ubuntu 14.04 Server - slow boot due to plymouth

Tags: 14.04, boot, plymouth

Just recently I have discovered the problem with plymouth on my server (had to restart it after updating everythig, haven't touch it since spring this year). A boot takes almost 10min. From dmesg:

```
[    4.916738] random: nonblocking pool is initialized
[   33.362902] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process (165) terminated with status 1
[   33.366476] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process ended, respawning
[   42.433275] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process (173) terminated with status 1
[   42.436779] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process ended, respawning
[   53.480571] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process (178) terminated with status 1
[   53.484704] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process ended, respawning
[  100.829265] Adding 16775164k swap on /dev/sda5.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:16775164k FS
```

I tried to deactivate plymouth in grub as I do not need any splash screen but clean console only. The only success is the fact that gfx is not initialized. But boot takes ages.

How to fix that?